# jquery div scroll style coverflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to achieve this [effect](http://www.eyecon.ro/spacegallery/#about)

but I need to replace images by container (div)

something like:

```
<div id="myGallery">
                <img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" />
                <img src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg"  />
                <img src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" />
                <img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" />

            </div>
```

by

```
<div id="myGallery">
        <div id="item1">contenido uno</div>
        <div id="item2">contenido dos</div>
        <div id="item3">contenido tres</div>
        <div id="item4">contenido cuatro</div>
        </div>
```

any ideas or any plugin?

Comment: Have you tried the referenced plug with your divs?

Comment: yes, but the effect did not result

Comment: Let me try something and let you know in a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a peek at [this demo](http://demo.rickyh.co.uk/spacegallery-moostyle/) – it looks like it does what you want, and it shouldn't be too hard to modify the ideas from it for your purposes.